# Why do I get Error: /invalidfileaccess in --file--

Tags: postscript

Based on [Simple way to add an image in postscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968443/simple-way-to-add-an-image-in-postscript) I wrote the following:

```
gsave
    360 72 translate                            % set lower left of image at (360, 72)
    230 346 scale                               % size of rendered image is 175 points by 47 points
    2304                                        % number of columns per row
    3456                                        % number of rows
    8                                           % bits per color channel (1, 2, 4, or 8)
    [2304 0 0 -3456 0 3456]                     % transform array... maps unit square to pixel
    (graphics/IMG_2216.jpg) (r) file /DCTDecode filter   % opens the file and filters the image data
    false                                       % pull channels from separate sources
    3                                           % 3 color channels (RGB)
    colorimage
grestore
```

but this gives:

> ```
> Error: /invalidfileaccess in --file--
> Operand stack:
>    2304   3456   8   --nostringval--   (graphics/IMG_2216.jpg)   (r)
> Execution stack:
>    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1894   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1877   1   3   %oparray_pop   1771   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
> Dictionary stack:
>    --dict:1166/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:126/200(L)--   --dict:136/228(L)--
> Current allocation mode is local
> ```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Are you using the `-DNOSAFER` option that the source answer recommends? File access is often disabled to avoid "malicious" code having too much access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply there is a problem accessing the file. Either the file does not exist in the specified location, or you do not have access rights to it.

Given that you are opening the file for read, the most likely is that the file doesn't exist. I notice that you haven't used a fully qualified path, perhaps you are executing the PostScript from the wrong location.

Comment: I added the fully qualified path. But I still get the same error:


    Error: /invalidfileaccess in --file--
    Operand stack:
       2304   3456   8   --nostringval--   (/home/cecil/postscript/graphics/IMG_2216.jpg)   (r)
`

The file exists and has the right properties:

`    -rw-r--r-- 1 cecil users 2,5M jul 24 13:58 /home/cecil/postscript/graphics/IMG_2216.jpg`

Comment: My comment is looking very bad. Is there a way to get the right lay-out?

Comment: I found the problem. I have several scripts where I used epstopdf to generate the PDF. This was one of the scripts where this was not converted to gs yet. After converting epstopdf to gs, it does what it should do.

Comment: By the way, when the file does not exist, you get: Last OS error: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

In case it isn't a file permissions issue, it may be a Ghostscript configuration issue.

One remedy is to create `$HOME/bin/gs` with contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$GS_NOSAFER" in
1|true|yes)
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin gs -dNOSAFER "$@";;
*)
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin gs "$@";;
esac
```

and make it executable.  This works because `$HOME/bin` is in my `$PATH` and the standard `gs` is in `/usr/bin`. Now I can export `GS_NOSAFER=1` to add that flag when running `gs`.

It turns out the [`pdfxup`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfxup) executable, which I was trying to use just now, needs this to work.

(This is for a Unix/Linux-like shell. On Windows, you can do something  equivalent.)